# Parsing bytes of a bitmap header and saving with file pointers

Tags: c, pointers, byte, fread

I'm working on my first project in my first C Programming class and am getting lost with pointers.  We are to alter bitmaps in various ways and I'm having a hard time with understanding how I can use file pointers to grab byte data I want to use and manipulate.  I know the bitmap file header and DIB header structure as well as the byte offset for the values that comprise them.  However, I'm having difficulty understanding how to save each of those values for use later with file pointers. Since this is for a project I don't want to ask for too much help.  Here is my code so far and various means I've attempted to capture parts of the header:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    FILE *fp;
    char buff[2]; //only trying '2' to try and capture 'BM' at start of file.
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r+b");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long fsize = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);

    // this is where I test what to do but can't get it correct
    unsigned short filetype = fgetc(fp);
    printf("First letter of filetype %c\n", filetype); //prints 'B' which is awesome

    //Now I do not understand how to capture both the 'BM'.
    //I've changed to use the fread as follows:
    fread(buff, sizeof(char), 2, fp);
    printf("Captured bytes with fread %s\n", buff) //this prints 4 char's and not 2? 

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I also tested a simple while loop to traverse the entire file and print each character until `EOF` is encountered using `fgetc` which worked.  So I'm assuming that with each call of `fgetc` it changes the location of the pointers current byte position to current position + 1.

I guess I'm not fully grasping how the file pointer can be used to save numerous bytes into a single stored variable.  I've also tried `fseek` and `fgets` to no avail.

I'd appreciate any help and input I can get from the community here.

Comment: To gauge your current understanding: What is a string in C?

Comment: @immibis array of characters

Comment: How do functions like `printf` know where the end is?

Comment: @immibis null terminated

Comment: So why did you pass an array that contains no NULs to `printf`?

Comment: @Pwrcdr87 After you store two characters in buf[0] and buf[1], and buf is only 2 characters long, is there a null terminator in buf?

Comment: @immibis ahhhh.... .I see what you did there.  Sneaky sneaky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf("%s", buff)` prints the character pointed by `buff` and subsequent characters until it reaches a NUL character. Unfortunately, `buff` only contained `B` and `M`, so `printf` kept reading past the end of the array until it found a NUL. That's bad!

Replace

```
char buff[2];
fread(buff, sizeof(char), 2, fp);
```

with

```
char buff[3];
size_t num_read = fread(buff, sizeof(char), 3, fp);
buff[num_read] = 0;
```

---

Note that `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`.

Note that `fgetc` advanced the file pointer beyond the `B`, so you'll need to rewind it once more if you want the `fread` to read the `B`.

Comment: That makes sense.  I really appreciate your example.  That helps to clear that up.

Comment: Commenting to your edit:  I know that I'll have to continually advance and bring back the file pointer as I traverse the pixel data when I want to alter their values.  I was just having a heck of a time trying to grasp how I can save header parameters to variables for use later on.  You and immibis really helped.

Comment: I was pretty sure you'd figure that bit out, but just making sure :)

Comment: Yep!  After not realizing the null terminator bit, you had every reason to think I wouldn't have figured that out!  haha